# Solving ODE having function which changes conditionally

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I want to solve the following set of ODE with a piecewise function A[t] which changes if a certain condition is satisfied.

```
eq1 = y1''[t] + 0.5 y2'[t] + 0.7 y1[t] + A[t] == 0;

eq2 = y2''[t] + 0.3 y1'[t] + 1.3 y2[t] == 0;

A[t]=0 when y1[t]<=y2[t] for all t

A[t]=Sin[t] when y1[t]>y2[t] for all t

y1'[0] == 1, y1[0] == 0, y2'[0] == 1, y2[0] == 0
```

I have tried with `WhenEvent` inside `NDSolve`, but it only gives correct result if `A[t]` is purely discrete using 'DiscreteVariables' option. The following is the code for that.

```
ti = 0; tf = 30;

eq1 = y1''[t] + 0.5 y2'[t] + 0.7 y1[t] + A[t] == 0;

eq2 = y2''[t] + 0.3 y1'[t] + 1.3 y2[t] == 0;

sol = NDSolve[{eq1, eq2, y1'[ti] == 1, y1[ti] == 0, y2'[ti] == 1, y2[ti] == 0, 
     A[ti] == If[y1[ti] <= y2[ti], 0, 10], {WhenEvent[y1[t] <= y2[t], 
       A[t] -> 0], WhenEvent[y1[t] > y2[t], A[t] -> 10]}}, {y1, y2, A}, {t, 
       ti, tf}, DiscreteVariables -> A][[1]];

Plot[Evaluate[{y1[t], y2[t], A[t]} /. sol], {t, ti, tf}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

So, please help and suggest if I want to use `A[t]` as mentioned earlier.

Comment: Why not use `Piecewise[]`?

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. Piecewise[] is also not working. I tried with this:---
ti = 0; tf = 30;
A[t_] := Piecewise[{0, y1[t] <= y2[t]}, {10*Sin[t], y1[t] > y2[t]}]
eq1 = y1''[t] + 0.5 y2'[t] + 0.7 y1[t] + A[t] == 0;
eq2 = y2''[t] + 0.3 y1'[t] + 1.3 y2[t] == 0;
sol = NDSolve[{eq1, eq2, y1'[ti] == 1, y1[ti] == 0, y2'[ti] == 1, 
     y2[ti] == 0}, {y1, y2, A}, {t, ti, tf}][[1]];
Plot[Evaluate[{y1[t], y2[t]}], {t, ti, tf}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. But, defining A[t] as piecewise function prior to NDSolve is not solving the issue, because there is no y1[t] and y2[t] values to check before solving the eqns. So, I think, the checking is to be done in every time step (t) within NDSolve.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to use `Piecewise`, which might well be what [Guess who it is.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/guess-who-it-is) had in mind.

```
ti = 0; tf = 30;
eq1 = y1''[t] + 0.5 y2'[t] + 0.7 y1[t] + A[t] == 0;
eq2 = y2''[t] + 0.3 y1'[t] + 1.3 y2[t] == 0;

{sol} = NDSolve[{
    eq1, eq2, y1'[ti] == 1, y1[ti] == 0, y2'[ti] == 1, y2[ti] == 0, 
    A[t] == Piecewise[{{Sin[t], y1[t] > y2[t]}}, 0]},
  {y1, y2, A}, {t, ti, tf}];

Plot @@ {Through[{y1, y2, 10 A[#] &}[t]] /. sol, Flatten[{t, y1["Domain"] /. sol}]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: That's exactly it, yes. :D (Please settle for an upvote IOU for the time being…)